# Previous/next function for custom QGIS form

Tags: qgis, qgis-customization

I'm currently working on a custom form in QGIS for archaeological application.

Basically, the custom form is used to read and write information about the walls and structures we found on field. Each item has two unique identification "numbers" : one is the "field number" we give to each find (it combines letters and numbers : *zxxfxxx*) and the other is a number automatically generated by the Postgresql database where all the data is stored.

I would like to implement previous and next buttons so that I can browse through my items. I have a rough idea of what I must do (i.e. attach a python script to my form and inside it work with iterations) but I don't know how to put all that together.

Could someone point me the way to go ? I had a look at the Selenext plugin but I don't know what is relevant in it in my case and how it could be attached to a form.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [Feature iterator plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FeatureIterator/) with great success.

It allows you to iterate through a vector layer. You can also filter by attribute values. That way you can easily loop through all features where `description` is `NULL`. Makes for a nice workflow for going through and edit all features that are missing values.

Comment: Thx, I'll have a look at this plugin ! It might be a good workaround, but unfortunately it's not compatible with the version of QGIS we use at work (Essen, 14.4). I suppose they might upgrade our softwares in due time...
Moreover, what I'd like to do is actually implement this function in the custom form to simplify the user experience...